# Is it possible to access component props in an event handler in Svelte?

Tags: events, svelte, svelte-3

Suppose I have a component with a `on:click` as well as a prop called `name` called `NameHandler`. Now let's say I want to change `name` when `on:click` occurs, without changing `NameHandler`, and without binding the `name` to another variable.

So something like this:

```
<script>
const nameHandlerClick = (/*usually empty since I don't use event*/) => {
    component.name = randomName(); //replace component.name with a way to access name prop in NameHandler.
}
</script>

<NameHandler {name} on:click={nameHandlerClick}/>
```

Comment: your component is not valid, name is not defined. what does 'a prop called name called NameHandler' means ?

Comment: I meant a component called `NameHandler`, which has a prop `name`. Does that clear your confusion?

Comment: i.e. `NameHandler.svelte` with `<script>export let name;</script>`

Comment: the component you wrote in your question is not valid, name is still not defined.

Comment: It's just an imaginary component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `NameHandler` is [forwarding the click event from the DOM](https://svelte.dev/docs#on_component_event) so we can attach an `on:click` to it.

If you don't want to store `name` in another variable, you can [bind](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_component) to the component and update the prop using the [client-side component API](https://svelte.dev/docs#$set).

```html
<script>
    import NameHandler from './NameHandler.svelte';
    let comp;
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        comp.$set({ name: 'updated' });
    }
</script>

<NameHandler bind:this={comp} on:click={handleClick} />
```

However, this is not a very Svelte-y way of doing things -- the client-side API is intended to be used by outside users of Svelte components, not from within a Svelte component. The more idiomatic way would be declaring `name` as its own variable and setting it directly.

```html
<script>
    import NameHandler from './NameHandler.svelte';
    let name = 'initial';
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        name = 'updated';
    }
</script>

<NameHandler {name} bind:this={comp} on:click={handleClick} />
```